# Jquery custom photo slideshow displaying all images simultaneously instead of one then the next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I followed a tutorial on youtube to make a photo ...reel? ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yikHrIMsccw )and cannot for the life of me figure out why my photos are displaying the same as before I did the code. They are supposed to fade in and out every 3 seconds in a loop. I have 8 photos which shouldn't matter to my knowledge and understanding of the written code.

```
    function Slider() {
$(".photoSlider#1").show("fade", 300);
$(".photoSlider#1").delay(3000).hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 300);

var sliderCount = $(".slider img").size();
var count = 2;

setInterval(function () {
    $(".photoSlider#" + count).show("slide", { direction: 'right' }, 300);
    $(".photoSlider#" + count).delay(3000).hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 300);

    if (count >= sliderCount) {
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count = count + 1;
    }//end if/else statement
}, 3600);//end setinterval
}//end function slider
```

here is my javascript, jqueryui and jquery library api's from google are in my head tag.

```
    <div class="photoSlider">
                    <img id="1" src="~/Content/Photos/photo1.jpg" />
                    <img id="2" src="~/Content/Photos/photo2.jpg" />
                    <img id="3" src="~/Content/Photos/photo3.jpg" />
                    <img id="4" src="~/Content/Photos/photo4.jpg" />
                    <img id="5" src="~/Content/Photos/photo5.jpg" />
                    <img id="6" src="~/Content/Photos/photo6.jpg" />
                    <img id="7" src="~/Content/Photos/photo7.jpg" />
                    <img id="8" src="~/Content/Photos/photo8.jpg" />
                </div>
```

here is my html for the slider

```
    .photoSlider{
        width:600px; overflow:hidden;margin:30px auto;
        background-image:url(~/Content/Photos/loading.gif);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
    }


    .photoSlider img {
        width:600px;
        display:none;
    }
```

and this is the css I have applied to the html. With the

```
    display:none;
```

it doesn't show the pictures at all, which it's supposed to do, but the javascript should fade them in right? Also according to the tutorial the background image (just a circle.gif that spins) should show behind the pictures, but when they don't show, neither does it.

Comment: Do you have `jquery` included in your projects head?

Comment: Yes I do. :/ can you think of anything else?

Comment: Where do you call your function... `Slider()` ?

Comment: Within my body tag I have the following code

Comment: <body onload="Slider();">

Comment: You have some typos in your images id 1 and 7

Comment: Sorry about those, that was from removing the alt keyword and changing names of photos, actual code is typo free.

Comment: How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/sj390avs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (or one of the problems) is the selectors you are using.

You are using `.photoSlider#1`. That means an element that has the the id `1` and the class `photoSlider`.

You should use `.photoSlider #1` (note the space). That means an element that has the id `1`, and has an ancestor with the class `photoSlider`.

I still get errors in the console when I run your code with this modification though, so you have some more work to do. At least this explains why no images are appearing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check this modified version:

```
$(function(){
  $("img").hide();
  function Slider() {
     $("#1").show("fade", 300);
     $("#1").delay(3000).hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 300);
     var sliderCount = $(".photoSlider img").size();
     var count = 2;

     setInterval(function () {
       $("#" + count).show("slide", { direction: 'right' }, 300);
       $("#" + count).delay(3000).hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 300);
       count >= sliderCount?count = 1:count = count + 1;
     }, 3600);//end setinterval
 }//end function slider

Slider();
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/sj390avs/1/